# How put images AND videos in the SAME slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have to make a slideshow with pictures and some videos in Vanilla JS.
Everything works OK for pictures (I put the pictures sources in the HTML img tag with innerTML), but when a video comes, the source is also put in the img tag, so it didn't work.
How can I display both (videos and photos) in the same slideshow ?
Can I change the img tag for a video tag when a video comes ? I don't be able to do that...

Here is my JS code:

```
// Attente du chargement de la page
window.onload = () => {
 
  //Selection des éléments
  //Tous les éléments de la gallery (photos et videos)
  const gallery = document.querySelectorAll('.profil_image');
  //Longueur de la galerie
  const totalGallery = gallery.length;
  //Lightbox
  const lightbox = document.querySelector('.lightbox');
  //Photo de la lightbox
  const lightboxImg = document.querySelector('.lightbox_picture');
  //Titre de l'image ou video
  let lightboxTitle = document.querySelector('.lightbox_picture_title');
  //Bouton fermeture lightbox
  const closeButton = document.querySelector('.lightbox_close')
  //Bouton retour/suivant de la lightbox
  const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.lightbox_previous');
  const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.lightbox_next');

  for (let i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
    let newIndex = i; // Remplacement de i par newIndex
    let clickedImgIndex = "";
    gallery[i].onclick = () => {
      // si imageUrl fini par mp4
      // img devient video
      function preview() {
        //Source de l'image cliquée
        let imageUrl = gallery[newIndex].src
        lightboxImg.src = imageUrl;
        //Titre de l'image cliquée
        let imageTitle = gallery[newIndex].alt
        lightboxTitle.textContent = imageTitle
        let extension = imageUrl.split('.').pop()
        console.log(lightboxImg); //extension jpg

//METTRE UNE LIGNE IMG l'autre VIDEO, hid une quand on affiche l'autre !

        if (extension != "jpg") {
          lightboxImg.tagName = "VIDEO"
          //<img src="" class="lightbox_picture"></img>
        }
      }
      preview();
      //Si index 0 bouton prev invisible
      if (newIndex == 0) {
        prevBtn.style.display = 'none';
      }
      //Si index final bouton next invisible
      if (newIndex >= totalGallery - 1) {
        nextBtn.style.display = 'none';
      }
      //Défilement photos précédentes
      prevBtn.onclick = () => {
          newIndex--; //décrément l'index
          if (newIndex == 0) {
            preview();
            prevBtn.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            preview()
            nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
          }
      }
      //Défilement photos suivantes
      nextBtn.onclick = () => {
          newIndex++; //décrément l'index
          if (newIndex >= totalGallery - 1) {
            preview()
            nextBtn.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            preview()
            prevBtn.style.display = 'block';
          }
    }
      //Apparition lightbox
      lightbox.classList.add("show");
      //Fermeture lightbox + reinitialisation bouton
        closeButton.onclick = () => {
          newIndex = clickedImgIndex;
          prevBtn.style.display = 'block';
          nextBtn.style.display = 'block';
          lightbox.classList.remove("show");
        }
}}};
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="lightbox">
      <button class="lightbox_close">X</button>
      <button class="lightbox_next">Next</button>
      <button class="lightbox_previous">Prev</button>
      <div class="lightbox_container">
        <img src="" class="lightbox_picture">
        <h2 class="lightbox_picture_title"></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If someone has an advice !
Tks a lot !

Comment: I have an idea how about make image stacking on video and when video come the img tag will be hide ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Error2.0 , your idea opened my mind ! :P
I solved my problem with an img tag for images and a video tag for videos. When a video comes, a hide the image a show the video and vice versa !
I don't understand why I don't think at this solution before !!!